# How to not execute jsp code inside jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have a requirement where i have to create widgets and display the source code on the web page to the user. The source code is jsp. But how can i stop executing jsp inside jsp page.

Is there any way? 
Thanks.

Comment: make it a string..isnt that obvious...or else much better load it from a txt file within your server..

Comment: Read [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-import-another-web-page-into-my-jsp-and-display-its-source-code.html).

Comment: i think Boris gives the answer to the question